# FileUtil.fullyDeleteContents does not work

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs

I've written a script. It is supposed to copy certain types of files from certain directories into other directories(which it should clean before hand). It copies everything but doesn't clean the directories. There are no errors or exeptions.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path, FileUtil}

val conf = new Configuration()
val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)

val listOfFileTypes = List("mta", "rcr", "sub")
val listOfPlatforms = List("B", "C", "H", "M", "Y")

for(fileType <- listOfFileTypes){
  FileUtil.fullyDeleteContents(new File("/apps/hive/warehouse/soc.db/fct_evkuzmin/file_" + fileType))
  for (platform <- listOfPlatforms) {
    var srcPaths = fs.globStatus(new Path("/user/com/data/" + "20170404" + "_" + platform + "/*" + fileType + ".gz"))
    var dstPath = new Path("/apps/hive/warehouse/soc.db/fair_usage/fct_evkuzmin/file_" + fileType)

    for(srcPath <- srcPaths){
      println("copying " + srcPath.getPath.toString)
      FileUtil.copy(fs, srcPath.getPath, fs, dstPath, false, conf)
    }
  }
}
```

Why doesn't FileUtil.fullyDeleteContents work?

Comment: You'll need the whole url. I guess you're not the first one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767607/delete-hdfs-folder-from-java